# Weak Convergence in the function space $L^1$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, weak-convergence

Im reading https://epubs.siam.org/doi/abs/10.1137/S0036141096303359?journalCode=sjmaah page $13$ for exact reference. I think the authors invoke a well known result regarding weak convergence which i'm failing to spot.

The author claims a weak convergence in the function space $L^1([0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d)$ specifically, assume for any $t\in[0,T]$ we have the following two bounds

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|x|^2\rho_h(t,x)dx \leq C $$

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^d} \max \big\{\rho_h(t,x)\log(\rho_h(t,x)),0\big\}dx\leq C $$
then they claim that (taking a sub sequence if necessary) there exists a $\rho\in L^1([0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that

$$ \rho_h \overset{w}{\to}\rho,  $$

where $\overset{w}{\to}$ refers to the weak convergence in $\rho\in L^1([0,T]\times\mathbb{R}^d)$.

$\textbf{Question :}$ can anyone see why this is true?

Comment: I think this is a consequence of the Dunford -Pettis criterion for weak/weak-sequential compactness in $L^{1}$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I will look this up, thank you for your comment :)

Comment: I would rather think of Lions's trichotomy. The first condition prevents vanishing, while the second one prevents concentration, thus we must have compactness. This is just a rough heuristic, though.